# Spring Cloud Config Authentication Issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying to configure Spring Cloud Config for one of my projects. It used to work fairly well before. However with latest version of Spring I am landing into trouble when I am trying to enable authentication. This is the log I see.

```
INFO  Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
WARN  Could not locate PropertySource: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
INFO  The following profiles are active: development
```

Has anybody faced this problem? Without authentication spring-cloud-config-client works well but with basic authentication enabled the same code doesn't work.

**Spring Cloud Config Server application.properties:**

```
spring.application.name=my-config
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///repo/my-config
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=root
```

**Spring Cloud Config Client Bootstrap.yml:**

```
spring.application.name=my-service
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.cloud.config.username=root
spring.cloud.config.password=root
```

Both my config server and the service projects use the same version property for Spring Boot and Spring Cloud

```
<spring-boot.version>2.2.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<spring-cloud-config.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-config.version>
```

====== Additional Information ======

Somehow the my-service project was not detecting the spring.profiles.active=development configuration I was specifying in my bootstrap.properties. I confirmed this by attempting to output this configuration in my code.

```java
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private String activeProfile;

logger.info("Active Profile: " + activeProfile);
```

Strangely the logger output was blank which meant that there is no active profile. So it is clear that this bootstrap.properties configuration is being ignored. To bypass this I added this JVM argument in my-service bootup.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=development -Dspring.application.name=my-service
```

This effectively fixed the profile not being detected issue. However I am still not clear why spring.profiles.active=development configuration is being ignored from my bootstrap.properties.

Comment: what is your spring security configuration on config server?

Comment: I have listed my config server application.properties file in my post. Is there anything specific I need to list.

Comment: That's not spring security configuration. Are you doing any custom spring security config in java code?

Comment: Try changing the profile of server to native, if that works,there might be an issue with your git uri or authentication with same

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for clarifying, I think I should have read your comment more carefully. I don't have any separate Spring Security file defined in my my-config or my-service project. I didn't think about defining it.

Comment: @Ashutosh can you tell me how to change profile of my config server to native. Is it the spring.profiles.active=development configuration which I need to tweak.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Server Side - application.properties**

   ```
   server.port=8888
   spring.application.name=config-service
   spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${repo_uri}
   spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=${git_username}
   spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=${git_password}
   spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
   spring.security.user.name=admin
   spring.security.user.password=admin
   ```
2. **Client Side - Application.properties**

   ```
   spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888
   spring.cloud.config.username=admin
   spring.cloud.config.password=admin
   spring.profiles.active=dev
   ```

   Here I have added the spring security dependency in the config server and set the username and password. And in config client we will be providing the same username and password to connect with the config server. Also I have added the active profile in config client so it will fetch the environment specific properties from the config server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `native` profile in "config-server" app whereas leave the `development` profile to clients. Below configuration works:

**config-server**

1. bootstrap.yml

   ```
   server:
     port: 9001
     servlet.context-path: /my-config-server

   spring:
     application.name: my-config-server
     profiles:
       active: native
     main:
       banner-mode: "OFF"
     cloud:
       config:
         uri: http://localhost:9001/my-config-server
         fail-fast: true
         username: root
         password: root
   ```
2. application.yml:

   ```
   spring:
     profiles: native
     cloud:
       config:
         server:
           native:
             searchLocations: file:<path-to-files>
             git:
               clone-on-start: false # Only clone(true) on-demand
   ```

**Config-Client**

1. bootstrap.yml

   ```
   spring:
     application.name: user-api
     profiles:
       active: development
     main:
       #banner-mode: "OFF"
     cloud:
       config:
         uri: http://localhost:9001/my-config-server
         fail-fast: true 
         username: root
         password: root
   ```

Comment: I tried the config-server configuration and I observed the following line on my console "Using generated security password: 8e9fc620-0bf8-4a5c-8e3b-c135c84d1af4". After this I tried logging into the config-server using the URL "http://localhost:9001/my-config/login" but login failed. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: try replacing 'spring.security.user.name=root' and 'spring.security.user.password=root' with "spring.cloud.config.username" and "spring.cloud.config.password" in both server/client. see https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#_security_2

Comment: Let me know if you have resolved the issue, otherwise we can review it further

Comment: Client side, gives cannot resolve properties. Whats wrong ?